# AT command AT+CPMS="SM","SM","MT"

Tags: mobile, communication, nokia, at-command

I needed a clarification about the AT command AT+CPMS="SM","SM","MT"

Although this AT command work with most of the UEs,it however gives an error msg with the Nokia N72...
I tried the AT command AT+CPMS=? & the mobile's response was "+CPMS: (),(),()" & 
I tried the AT command AT+CPMS? & the response was "+CPMS: ,,,,,,,,".
Does this mean that the mobile does not allow the user to acces the memory location...

Also if possible could you tell me the at commands not supported by this phone or the alternate AT commands for the mobile.

Help on this will be very much appreciated!!!

Answer (score 2):

In order to know if a command is supported or not you have to call AT+CLAC. The supported AT commands are described in a nokia document you can find on their developer forum.